# Agora live video streaming

Tags: agora.io

The way live streaming price structure is mentioned on the website with a foot note that it's applicable to only audience minutes is quite confusing , and since I am not being to get any answer from the sales team or contact them , I want to know if I use live streaming API in my website , and then suppose I buy 1000 minutes from agora , after which i live stream for 20 minutes to 10 people , then after the live stream will I(the host) be left with 800 minutes or 980 minutes .

Answer (score 1):

Agora pricing model is "pay as you go" and If you stream 20 min to 10 people(audience) + 1 host

~Usage will be:
200 min for the audience downstream

20 min for the host upstream

= 220 min of total usage.

I would recommend you to take a look at the pricing doc https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/billing_interactive_broadcast?platform=All%20Platforms and reach out to Agora sales team for more details.